# Why does the vue effect not run through the scheduler when the effect is initialized?

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

Why does the vue effect not run through the scheduler when the effect is initialized?

```js
effect(
  () => {
    console.log('effect');
  },
  {
    scheduler: (job) => {
      console.log('run by scheduler');
      job();
    },
  },
);
```

Why was it designed this way?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make the effect run through the scheduler when it inits.

```js
const scheduler = (job) => {
  console.log('run by scheduler');
  job();
}

const e = effect(
  () => {
    console.log('effect');
  },
  {
    scheduler,
    lazy: true,
  },
);
scheduler(e) // init run
```